# How to compute the number of occurrences of a string in the entire workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I want to compute number of times a specified string appears in my entire workbook in some column. I have tried this formula `=COUNTIF(sheet1:sheetn!C2:C150; "*string*")` But it renders the `#VALUE!` error.

What's wrong with my formula? How can I get this count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the equivalent **VBA** code to count the number of **cells** containing at least one *string*

```
Sub StringCounter()
    Dim r As Range, s As String, i As Long
    s = "*string*"
    For Each sh In Sheets
        Set r = sh.Range("C2:C150")
        i = i + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(r, s)
    Next sh
    MsgBox i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

Here is the code to count the **number of strings**  It will count multiple *string* within a single cell:

```
Sub StringCounter_II_The_Sequel()
Dim r As Range, s As String, i As Long
Dim rr As Range, L As Long
s = "string"
L = Len(s)
For Each sh In Sheets
    Set r = sh.Range("C2:C150")
        For Each rr In r
            txt = rr.Text
            If InStr(txt, s) > 0 Then
                i = i + (Len(txt) - Len(Replace(txt, s, ""))) / L
            End If
        Next rr
Next sh
MsgBox i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2:**

The *math* works as follows:

1. say there are three *string* in a cell and the number of characters in that cell is 100
2. the *replace* removes all three instances and the new length is 82
3. the subtract results in 18
4. the division results in 3 (because the word *string* is 6 characters long)

Comment: Thanks Gary. But if *string* appears many times in a cell, it's counted just once ! why ?

Comment: @mounaim  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Can you please explain the if clause ?

Comment: @mounaim  The **IF** makes sure there is at least one *string* in a cell before performing any time-consuming math with that cell.

Comment: I was in fact talking about the inside statement sorry Gary

Comment: Brilliant formula @Gary's I get it now ! thank you very much :)

Comment: for your edit number 2 I think you must state that each string is 6 characters long

Comment: @mounaim  I added the explanation as per your request

Answer (score 1):

You need to define each range for each sheet e.g.

```
COUNTIF(Sheet1!C2:C150,"*string*")+COUNTIF(Sheet2!C2:C150,"*string*") ...
```

If you want to be clever, you can say put each sheet in the column A, and in column B use

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet"&A1&"!A1:A5"),"*string*")
```

Or whatever fits your naming scheme. Then drag it down for each count and sum that.

Comment: I've lot of sheets :/ isn't there a way to avoid the long formula ?

Comment: @mounaim you could write a macro. Or have a reference column for each sheet, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: I'll try to write a macro for this since I'm beginner in VBA

Answer (score 1):

You can write a pretty straightforward user-defined function in VBA to do this. Paste the following code into a new module (for instructions on how to do this, see [this post](https://superuser.com/q/801609/76571)):

```
Public Function WBCountString(SearchFor As String, InRange As Range) As Long
Dim wbcs As Long, rng As Range, addr As String
For Each s In Worksheets
    'Limit search area to specified range.
    addr = InRange.Address
    Set rng = s.Range(addr)
    'Keep a running tally of the number of instances of the word in the specified range on each sheet.
    wbcs = wbcs + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, "*" & SearchFor & "*")
Next s
WBCountString = wbcs
End Function
```

Once you have this code in a module, you can use the function from the worksheet. For example, to count the number of instances of `potato` in column C on all worksheets, you would use the following syntax.

```
=WBCountString("potato",C:C)
```

Comment: I'm having an error, When I put the function in some new sheet with C:C range, Excel circumvent the C column of the active worksheet and returns just 0, I think some referencing problem is happening here

Comment: @mounaim You can't put the formula in the C column or else it will introduce a circular reference error. Your options are either to refer to a part of the C column instead (e.g., `C1:C20`) and put your formula outside that range, or just put your formula somewhere else on the sheet.

Comment: OK I get it now and I have corrected the error :) just one remark, if my string appears twice in a cell, it's computed only once :) why ?

Comment: @mounaim I'm using COUNTIF, which counts cells. I (wrongly) assumed from what you had tried that counting cells would be sufficient.

Comment: Oh I see ! may be I didn't mention it clearly, but this is what I wanted to do in fact