# Trying to highlight unique values across multiple sheets in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, macros

I am trying to compare the values from column A of `Sheet1` (which I have renamed "AR") and column A of `Sheet2` (which I have renamed "Paste Here") and highlight rows containing values that do not exist on the other sheet. (Both columns end with an empty cell.) I found a macro that I thought did something similar to what I wanted here at [Efficient removal of duplicate records across multiple Excel sheets](https://superuser.com/questions/847989), and I am trying to modify it to meet my needs, but I can't make it work.
Currently when I run it, it locks Excel up and I have to do end task on Excel.

This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compare2()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim startRow As Integer
    startRow = 1

    Dim row As Integer
    row = startRow

    Dim bRow As Integer

    'sharks below, cap'ain
    ' This loop is looping on row.
    ' Scan down column AR!A (i.e., Sheet1!A) until we find an empty cell.
    Do While (Worksheets("AR").Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

        Dim aVal As String
        aVal = Worksheets("AR").Range("A" & row).Value
        bRow = startRow             'I see thy booty

        ' This loop is looping on bRow.  Scan down column 'Paste Here'!A
        ' (i.e., Sheet2!A) until we find an empty cell.
        Do While (Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & bRow).Value <> "")

            Dim aVal2 As String
            aVal2 = Worksheets("Paste Here").Range("A" & bRow).Value

            If (aVal <> aVal2) Then
                Worksheets("AR").Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                                ' we found a traitor; feed 'em to the sharks
                row = row - row
                Exit Do
            End If

            If (aVal2 <> aVal) Then
                Worksheets("Paste Here").Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                row = row - row
                Exit Do
            End If

            bRow = bRow + 1
        Loop

        row = row + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Any help you can provide would be helpful.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more clearly (in more detail) what you are trying to accomplish? Your VBA code makes my head swim (`row = row - row`?), but, from your current prose description, this sounds like something you should be able to do with worksheet functions and/or conditional formatting. Also, please be more explicit about "I can't seem to make it work."

Comment: Sure, I am trying to compare the values from column A of "AR" and column A of "Paste Here" and highlight whatever values do not exist on the other. Currently when I run it, it simply locks excel up and I have to end task on excel. Not really knowing VBA, I was just trying to modify found macro so I'm sure there is a much more elegant way of doing what I want.

Answer (score 0):

It’s too bad that you didn’t understand the subroutine
that you were cannibalizing better before you started modifying it.

- The “WalkThePlank” subroutine is looking for *matches*. 
  When it finds a row in `Sheet1` that matches a row in `Sheet2`,
  it takes action. 
  You’re looking for unique values;
  i.e., rows in `Sheet1` that don’t match anything in `Sheet2`, and vice versa. 
  But what you’re *doing* is triggering off pairs of rows that don’t match;
  i.e., if `Sheet1!Row 1` doesn’t match `Sheet2!Row 1`, you take action. 
  This is premature;
  you need to scan *all the way* through `Sheet2` to determine
  whether `Sheet1!Row 1` matches *any* row in `Sheet2`.
- The author of the “WalkThePlank” subroutine did something
  that doesn’t make a lot of sense. 
  After deleting the row indexed by the `row` variable, he set the variable to 0. 
  This was wasteful, as it caused the subroutine to re-examine
  all the `Sheet1` rows that it had already examined and determined to be unique. 
  But, since it deletes the row that’s not unique
  (i.e., that matches row `bRow` on `Sheet2`),
  it won’t look at *that* row again, and there isn’t an infinite loop. 
  To compound the curiosity, he could have said `row = 0`,
  but, instead, he cryptically said `row = row - row`.

  But you need to change that. 
  (To be more accurate, I believe that you should just
  eliminate the `row = …` statements inside the `Do While` loops;
  except for the `row = row + 1` at the end.) 
  Since you aren’t deleting rows,
  this *does* cause your macro to re-examine *the same data* over and over again;
  i.e., it is an infinite loop. 
  You need to just keep on marching down `Sheet1`.
- You may be able to abort a VBA infinite loop
  without killing Excel and losing your data
  by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>. 
  If your keyboard doesn’t have a <kbd>Break</kbd> key,
  try bringing up the on-screen keyboard by running `osk`
  and clicking on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>Pause</kbd>. 
  If that doesn’t work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>ScrLk</kbd>.

Super User is not a script-writing service. 
I think I’ve explained what’s going wrong well enough
that you should be able to fix it now. 
If you still can’t get it to work, come back and tell us where you got stuck.