# How to split numbers into columns with negative and positive values, without empty cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Given positive and negative values in column A of an Excel sheet, I want column B to list the positive values from column A, and column C to show the negative values, in the order in which they appear in column A.

However, I don't want any empty cells in columns B and C.

So, I do NOT want:

```
   A     B     C
----------------
 All   >=0    <0
 100   100
-300        -300
-800        -800
 900   900
 700   700
-200        -200
 900   900
```

But instead, I want:

```
   A     B     C
----------------
 All   >=0    <0
 100   100  -300
-300   900  -800
-800   700  -200
 900   900
 700
-200
 900
```

Comment: Your sample data does not demonstrate how you want to deal with either zeros or duplicate values in column A. A row of column headers so that the data actually starts in the second row may be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Not on a windows box. I bet there is a formula that would do it. VBA for sure:
In VB Editor click Insert Module then type:

```
Sub posInBnegInC(ByRef aList as range)
    Dim cll as Range
    For each Cll in AList
        If cll.value2 > 0 then
            Sheet2.Range("B65000").end(xlup).offset(1,0).value2 = cll.value2
        Else
            Sheet2.Range("C65000").end(xlup).offset(1,0).value2 = cll.value2
        End If
    Next cll
End Sub
```

You can add the logic to handle value of exactly 0 if such exists. As it is the code will copy the zeros to column C. If there is non-numeric data in column A it won't work, but i assume all A numeric. Then you can run in a variety of ways, including:

```
Sub DoIt()
    call posInBnegInC(Sheet1.Range("A2:A65000"))
End Sub
```

Comment: kindly tell exactly me how to use these codes. I don't know to use visual basic editor in excel. please help me....

Comment: Now that this question is locked: as one knows the row number for the result column, see Microsoft's [Excel: Finding the nth Value That Meets a Condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167) for a non-VBA solution.

Comment: In Excel press alt-F11. In last 2 or 3 versions of office you can right-click anywhere in the ribbon then click "Customize the Ribbon" and in the "Main Tabs" area on right click the box "Developer" and "OK". Then you can open the Visual Basic Editor with a button on the far left of the Developer tab. I will edit code to add Sheet1/2 stuff.

Comment: @Arjan I've been trying to apply the functions in your link without success. Not positive but think this may not be straightforward using functions without sorting input column and/or accepting blanks or duplicates in result columns. Even with overhead of learning a little VBA, i think it is more straightforward/easy.

Comment: @user3906491 you can omit Sheet1. and Sheet2. I had your question confused with another I was working on. Take some time to learn a tiny bit of VBA and it will make sense. Search for "VBA" and any snip of my code between dots. Also terms "Project Explorer", "Object Browser", and "Properties Window". There is a lot online. The Help in Excel/VBEditor is ok too - but searching better, i think.

Comment: @user3906491 Instructions for adding VBA code to your project can be found [here](http://superuser.com/q/801609/76571).

Comment: [Microsoft's explanation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167) works fine for me, klausnrooster and @user. In OpenOffice I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl3hC.png) when using the following array formula (note: save with Ctrl+Shift+Enter or Command+Shift+Enter, or something similar) in cell B2: `=index($A$2:$A$8; small( if($A$2:$A$8 >= 0; row($A$2:$A$8); ""); row($A$2:$A$8) - 1 ) - 1)` And the same with `<` instead of `>=` in cell C2. (Note that my OpenOffice uses `;` between function parameters, while Excel might want `,` there.)

Comment: My mistake - wasn't highlighting range before I did Ctlr-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking how to get the n-th *filtered value* from some column into the n-th *row* of another column.

Microsoft explains getting the n-th filtered value in [Excel: Finding the nth Value That Meets a Condition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167). This uses "array formulas" to perform calculations on items in an array (a list). Microsoft's example can be extended to the get the value matching a row number. If your array is in `A2:A8`, and you want to only show values `>= 0`, then the following can be used in `B2:B8` (not tested):

```
=iferror(index(A2:A8, small( if(A2:A8 >= 0, row()-1, ""), row()-1) ), "")
```

Be careful to enter this as an array formula: first select cells `B2` thru `B8`, then paste the above into the formula bar, and save it by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter (or Command+Return in Office on a Mac, or Command+Shift+Return in OpenOffice on a Mac).

For `C2:C8`, repeat with the `>= 0` condition replaced with `< 0`.

To decipher this step-by-step, I've added the following formulas to an OpenOffice Calc worksheet, with its results below. Note that in OpenOffice one [needs a semicolon to separate function parameters](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=116302), while in Excel one might need a comma, hence the semicolons in the next formulas.

[image: OpenOffice results]

In `D2:D8`:

```
=if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; "")
```

This shows the row number minus 1 if the value *in the same row* in `A2:A8` is positive, or an empty cell otherwise. Subtracting 1 converts rows 2 thru 8 into a position of 1 to 7, to ignore the first header row.

So, now we know that the 1st, 4th, 5th and 7th values from `A2:A8` are positive.

Next, in `E2:E8`:

```
=small( if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; ""); row()-1 )
```

This takes the earlier results as the input for `small(..., k)` [which](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07) takes the k-th smallest number shown earlier in `D2:D8`. (That list happens to be sorted from 1 to 7, but that is not even required for the `small` function.) Here, we set `k` to the current row number minus 1 to ignore the header row again. So for the 3rd row, we get the position of the 2nd positive value in `A2:A8`. But for `E6` and down no value is found, showing an error.

In `F2:F8`:

```
=index(A2:A8; small( if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; ""); row()-1 ))
```

This takes the *positions* 1, 4, 5 and 7 (and the errors) from the previous step as input for `index(..., k)`, [which](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) finds the k-th *value* from `A2:A8`, or an error if `k` is invalid.

Now, `F2:F8` still shows an error for the last rows. In Excel 2007 and later, one can use `iferror` to show nothing in case of an error, like used in the very first formula above. OpenOffice [does not support that](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=92677), but needs `if(iserror(...); ""; ...)`, replacing both `...` with the formula from `F2:F8`. Not nice.

Alternatively, use `index(A2:A9; ...)` to include cell `A9` when getting the actual value from the first column, and then somehow make OpenOffice use `small(...; 8)` if no more values are found. Like in `G2:G8`:

```
=if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; 8)
```

This still searches positive numbers in the 7 values from `A2:A8`, but now returns `8` if not positive.

In `H2:H8`:

```
=small( if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; 8); row()-1 )
```

And finally in `I2:I8`:

```
=index(A2:A9; small( if(A2:A8 >= 0; row()-1; 8); row()-1 ))
```

Here, the value `8` maps to the value in `A9`. In the example screenshot `A9` holds some dots, which are then shown in `H6:H8` as no more positive numbers are found.

Like Microsoft [writes](https://support.office.com/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7): *if you really want to master formulas in Excel, you need to know how to use array formulas*. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Arjan already mentioned this twice so but I'm trying to post this as an actual answer instead of a comment. He said the post is locked but I'm so fresh to Stack Exchange that I don't get why it's locked but I can still post this as an answer.
Anyway, Microsoft has an exact solution for this. I would only modify it slightly by wrapping it in IFERROR to return blank instead of #NUM! errors.

---

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101167
As the KB article states, be sure to enter them as array formulas

For the positives:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$8>0,ROW($A$2:$A$8),""),ROW()-1)-ROW($A$2:$A$8)+1),"")}
```

For the negatives:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,SMALL(IF($A$2:$A$8<0,ROW($A$2:$A$8),""),ROW()-1)-ROW($A$2:$A$8)+1),"")}
```