# if greater than zero copy from the range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have data sheet with "product" list in range `B38:B161` and "to order" column in range `I38:I161` which will be updated manually. So when cells in range "I" is updated with number to order, the product from range "B" will be copied to range `J38:J161` first empty cell. How can I achieve this?

Script I've got:

```
Sub copyAboveZero()

Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set sourceRng = ActiveSheet.Range("I38:I161")
i = 1

For Each cell In sourceRng
    If cell.Value > 0 Then
        cell.Resize(1, 1).Copy Destination:=Range("J" & i)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

But this code copies only range "I" more than zero cells, while what I want is to copy cells from Range "B" and paste it to range "J" if that makes sense.

Example data:

```
Column B   Column I   Column J

text1      0          text2
text2      6          text4
text3      0          text5
text4      12            
text5      24
```

Comment: Negative vote and "no comments" has become the way of life in SU. Anyway, I assume the negative vote is for no research effort this question shows.

Comment: @Arjan updated the tag (to MS Excel) - good point

Answer (score 1):

The is no need to use VBA to accomplish what you are asking for.

Use the following formula in column J against each product (item): `=IF(I2=0,0,B2)`.

This will put a value of zero in the column J when the value in the "To order" column is zero, when it is a non-zero number, it will copy the contents of cell in column B.

Comment: You'll need array formulas to get the result into *"first empty cell"* as requested. (As an aside, please [don't abuse line breaks for formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Thanks.)

Answer (score 0):

Like extensively explained in the duplicate [How to split numbers into columns with negative and positive values, without empty cells?](https://superuser.com/questions/852490/how-to-split-numbers-into-columns-with-negative-and-positive-values-without-emp/853882#853882) no need for any VBA. Instead, you'll need [an array formula](https://support.office.com/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) in `J38:J161`, such as:

```
=iferror(index(B38:B161, small(if(I38:I161>0, row()-37, ""), row()-37)), "")
```

[image]

For details, see the duplicate.

Comment: thank you guys it really helped and sorry I wasn't clear enough in the beginning its my first time ever posting on sites like that