# Copying data with regular intervals

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have data in Sheet 1, say rows 1,2,3,4...etc I want them to be put to Sheet2 with a gap of 20 lines in between each row.

How would I approach this?

Comment: You could copy and paste? Write a macro? Learn VBa?

Answer (score 0):

This VBa does it

Save a copy of your file first, just in case

```
Option Explicit

Sub WenchesAndMead()

Dim numberOfRowsGap As Integer
numberOfRowsGap = 20

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim otherRow As Integer
otherRow = 1

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(otherRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(row).Value
    otherRow = otherRow + numberOfRowsGap
    row = row + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)