# Getting last cell in row with data and corresponding data in column A in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, lookup

I have a spreadsheet that in column A lists dates. Column B may or may not have data in each cell.

The question I have is when I grab the last cell with data in column B, how can I also grab the corresponding data in column A?

On a separate sheet, I wish to have 3 cells with data:

Cell 1 = the data in the last cell containing data in column B

Cell 2 = the corresponding date in column A

Cell 3 = the header of column B (the header will be different every time)

I’m using  `=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B:B)` to get the last cell with data in column B

I'll then repeat for the last cell with data in columns C, D, etc…

Answer (score 2):

So this looks up the value of the last non-blank

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B:B)
```

So then, this would lookup the row of the last non-blank

```
=MATCH(9E+99+307,B:B,1)
```

If you want to know what's next to it, you can use indirect -

```
=INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(9E+99+307,B:B,1))
```

Or you could use an index/match (probably a **better choice**)

```
=INDEX(A:B,MATCH(9E+307,B:B,1),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With VBa, take a copy of the file first (there is no option to undo)

Try this

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThingy()

Dim row As Integer
row = 2                     'start at 2 because we have headers

Dim myDate As String
Dim myValue As String

Do While (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value <> "" Then
        myDate = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row).Value
        myValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & row).Value
    End If

    row = row + 1
Loop

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = myDate
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Value = myValue
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value
End Sub
```

Also see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Worksheet 1:

[image]

Worksheet 2 after I run the macro

[image]

Comment: Ideally though, I would like a way to have this repeat for every column that has a header.  That number varies from 2 to as many as 200. Any thoughts on that.

And again, thank you for the solution you provided.  That has gotten me much closer.

Comment: @Eric, is there always a single value in every row, so, for example, you wouldn't have a row where col B and colF and col K had values?

Comment: Also, do you expect only 1 set of results in Worksheet2, or do you expect multiple results? In your example, you'd see only 1 row, do you expect to see multiple rows in Worksheet2 (worksheet2 is basically just filtering out the empty spaces?)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LOOKUP` like this to get the last value in column B

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B:B)`

....then you can simply add another column as 3rd argument to return the corresponding cell from that column, i.e.

`=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,B:B,A:A)`

Answer (score 0):

The above are very creative solutions, but you don't really need to do anything fancy. Match supports the "*" syntax. So `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",B:B,-1))` will get you there:)