# Excel update cell when cell above is hidden by filter

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet with events - and a column with the weekday of the event

Some days have both 3 and 4 events
So, in column P, I filter out the duplicate days

[image]

As you can see, I have a filter on Q. If I filter the result to show only the 'X' marked rows, Tuesday will no longer be visible in row 3.
If I filter by X:
 - P3 will be tugged away
 - P4 will be empty

Instead P4 should update and show Tuesday, while P3 is filtered out. The field is not considered hidden by Excel - but is tugged away. Therefore, a normal 'is this hidden' check fails.

Preferably this should be handled in the function in column P
However a VBA or Conditional formatting solving the problem is also welcome :-)

Comment: What do you want to see in row 4? Right now your question is rather unclear. Please edit it further to improve it and make it more clear what you wish to see.

Comment: Perhaps including what you'd like the final data to look like would help, if you're having trouble describing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel function determine if a cell is visible](https://superuser.com/questions/885159/excel-function-determine-if-a-cell-is-visible)

Comment: Not a dublicate - The cell is not 'hidden' - but tugged away when the filter is used - so solutions there do not apply here...