# Excel Macro insert value into another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Okay I'm needing some help with excel i'm new to it. I have a spreadsheet that adds all these value together and puts them in cell M3. However this is a daily spreadsheet I will be using so I want to add a button that will run a macro to copy the value from M3 to N7 the first time I click it. But then the next time I click it I want it to copy the value from M3 to N8 and so on up to N37 for a months time.

I have been trying to get this done for awhile now and can't seem to find anything to help me thought I would ask here and also hoping someone would explain the code a bit for me so I can better understand it. I got the button added already so no need to tell me how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you post what you have so far? This requires using Visual Basic. Do you have any code yet? Where are you getting stuck? Have you tried using the macro recorder for some of the basic functionality?

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want.

When you run VBa, there is no undo, so take a backup of your file first and play with a copy!!

Please note the comments in the code, this is things you will need to update

I have also assumed you're not using worksheet2 so this code uses it!

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAsNewRow()

Dim sourceData As String
sourceData = "A1"                          'the column and row from where you want to copy FROM

Dim destinationData As String
destinationData = "B"                          'the column from where you want to copy TO

Dim newRow As Integer
newRow = 1
Do While (Range(destinationData & newRow).Value <> "")
    newRow = newRow + 1
Loop

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B" & newRow).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(sourceData).Value

End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Answer (score 2):

By using the function **Tools->Macro->Record New Macro...**, you can do all your operations like before (with Keyboard and Mouse) and after that (**stop record**) you can take a look at the **generated** macro-code.
This can help in many cases.

If you have any special problems, please post your code.

Answer (score 2):

Put any Shape or AutoShape on the worksheet and assign this macro to it:

```
Sub SaveResults()
    Dim N As Long
    If Range("N7").Value = "" Then
        N = 7
    Else
        N = Cells(Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    Cells(N, "N").Value = Range("M3").Value
End Sub
```