# Excel Spreadsheet sheet formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to be able to have a cell in a 2nd tab equal what was in a previous tab, then create a new tab, copy and paste and have the spreadsheet formula update to the previous tab instead of referencing the first tab.

Ie 
the formula for previous work in the 2 tab equals the value in the 1 tab completed to tab.

When I copy and paste into a new tab (3) to make the next progress sheet the sheet formula reference is still for the 1 tab instead of updating to the 2 tab. Is there a way around this?

Comment: No.  You will need to update the cell referencing manually or writing a VBA script that does that.

Comment: Since it appears you can't get what you want, an easy fix is to go to the 3rd tab and do a `find and replace`: `find` "sheet2", `replace` "sheet1" and click `replace all`.

Answer (score 3):

Excel can only reference sheets absolutely. Unlike cell references, which can be relative and change when copied, sheet references are always absolute.

Relative sheet references have been requested as a new Excel feature several times in the past, but so far not been implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Relative sheet referencing is fairly easy
if you’re willing to use a little VBA.  Create the following VBA function:

```
Function SHEET_OFFSET(Offset, Ref)
'   Returns cell contents at Ref, in sheet Offset
    Application.Volatile
    With Application.Caller.Parent
        SHEET_OFFSET = .Parent.Sheets(.Index + Offset) _
         .Range(Ref.Address).Value
    End With
End Function
```

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)
for general information on using VBA.

Then, if you want a cell in `Sheet2` to access `Sheet1!Q42`, but then,
when you *copy* from `Sheet2` to `Sheet3`,
you want the corresponding cell to access `Sheet2!Q42`, use the formula

```
SHEET_OFFSET(-1, Q42)
```

The first argument is the sheet number, relative to the current one,
and the second argument is the cell reference. 
When you copy this formula to `Sheet(n)`, it will automatically refer to `Sheet(n-1)`.