# Count number of selected cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I count the number of selected cells, regardless of cell content?.

There are two use cases. I need use case 2 right now:

1. When I make one or multiple selections, I want to know how many cells,
2. I want to select exactly N cells using multiple selections. I keep making and resizing selections until the number (which should be live on the screen somewhere) reaches N

For #1 I have a workaround: Select single cell containing text, copy (so it has an animated border), then make your selections, press paste, and read the count in the status bar.

For #2 I don't know a workaround that doesn't involve repeating workaround #1 dozens of times and then pressing undo.

[image]

Comment: Is point 2 saying you know you want to select A3:A6 and B:5 to B:11 and C1:C22 and you want to have a quickway to select them?

Comment: #2 could also be done with VBA but it is complex as you would need a way of accumulating the answer between cell selections. Possibly a button to start and another to reset. It would take a lot of working out. My advise would be to create a second question stating what you wanted to ACHIEVE so that you get some alternative approaches.

Comment: No, @Dave, I know I want to select, for example, 40 cells, and then I want to make selections in between existing appointments (like the image), until 40 cells are selected.

Comment: What is wrong with holding down CTRL and selecting the cells you want? Or do I still not understand the question :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address point #1, you can use this VBa. The problem is you don't explain how you want to see this detail!? So I've added it as a Message Box.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim totalCells As Long
totalCells = Selection.Cells.Count

MsgBox (totalCells)
End Sub
```

I added the VBa to Sheet1. Also see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Just don't select all cells as it will through an overflow exception

[image]

The problem is the pop up will occur every time, I'd suggest you replace

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

```
MsgBox (totalCells)
```

with

```
Range("M1").Value = totalCells ' CHANGE THE RANGE TO THE CELL YOU WANT
```

Comment: I changed the messagebox to `Application.StatusBar = totalCells` and that solved my point #2

Comment: Now if I could only make this script global so I can use it in all sheets of all workbooks, it would be awesome.

Comment: You could hack it and copy it to each, but your quesiton is good enough to ask a new quesiton!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think to do what you want would be with VBA.

If you wanted a function to put this in a cell - something like this would work:

```
Public Function cellcount()
Application.Volatile
cellcount = Selection.Cells.count
End Function
```

You can re-run the function by pressing F9 to get the answer after each selection change.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much, everyone. Your above info may be a few years old, but is exactly what I needed today. In case it generates ideas for someone else, here's how I tweaked the above for my needs. (Our cost isn't actually $2/hour, of course. But you get the idea.) Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const HOURS As Integer = 10        ' hours per cell
    Const COST As Integer = 2 * HOURS  ' dollars per cell
    Const SPACER As String = "   "

    Dim numCells As Long

    numCells = Selection.Cells.Count

    If numCells < 2 Then

        Application.StatusBar = False

    Else

        On Error Resume Next ' in case the selection is so large it causes an overflow error
        Application.StatusBar = "Cells: " & numCells _
                     & SPACER & "Hours: " & (numCells * HOURS) _
                     & SPACER & "Cost: " & FormatCurrency(numCells * COST, 0)

    End If

End Sub
```