# Counter in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, counter

My file has 50 sheet inside, which each sheet is a standard form. Lets name as Form1, Form2, Form3.

I want to create a print sheet, where I select which form I want to see, so that I don't need to navigate between sheet to find the wanted one.
And I want to have counter in this print sheet that It counts everytime I send to a printer.

What did I do so far?
I created this formula, where M1 is a drop-down list with the form names. So If I want to see the Form2, I select Form2 in the dropdown list, and the formula displays all Form2 sheet.

```
=IF($M$1="Form1";IF('Form1'!A1="";"";'Form1'!A1);"")&IF($M$1="Form2";IF('Form2'!A1="";"";'Form2'!A1);"")&IF($M$1="Form3";IF('Form3'!A1="";"";'Form3'!A1);"")
```

It's working fine, because all forms are standardized.

After choosing the selected form, I need to insert a ID number from my company and then print it.

I would like to know if it's possible to create a counter in this sheet that counts how many times I printed... Or anything that would count in chronological order when I save or change anything...

Answer (score 1):

All of your requests can be accommodated. But only using VBA I'm afraid.

Keep the dropdown but also add a button that triggers a macro.

In the macro, read the cell with the dropdown and send the appropriate sheet to print. Then update the appropriate counter which can be in a set of cells on the same page as the dropdown and button.

To count the number of saves, you need a macro that before_save function. You need to search for that, I think there may even be an article about it on my blog, can't remember, it's been a few years since I've done it. The principal is the same as the previous macro in that you simply add 1 to the appropriate cell.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat cleaner way of building the “print sheet”
that will show the contents of one of the other 50 sheets
is to set cell `A1` to

```
=INDIRECT($M$1 & "!A1")
```

which builds a text string
that looks like the qualified name of the cell that you want to see,
and then uses the `INDIRECT()` function to de-reference that string
(i.e., to treat it as a cell address
and retrieve the contents of the identified cell). 
With this, you won’t need to change your formula(s)
when you add `Form51`.  Warnings:

- This may cause Excel to do a lot of work
  (i.e., spend a lot of time) “recalculating” these indirect cells
  whenever *anything* changes (not just `M1`). 
  I’m not sure whether it would be any worse than what you have now.
- Be sure to avoid the temptation to change data or enter new data
  into the “print sheet” when you want to update `Form42`. 
  (Of course, you have this issue now.) 
  You may be able to protect yourself from such accidents
  by protecting the print sheet.

There are other ways to construct the print sheet; e.g., using VBA to

- create a user-defined function that might replace the `INDIRECT()` call,
  but operate more smoothly, or
- actually copy all the data from `Formnn` to the print sheet
  whenever you change `M1`.

You can count changes by writing a `Worksheet_Change` VBA routine.

I don’t know any way for the sheet’s logic to be able to count/detect
when you print it.  However, you might be able to achieve the desired effect
by writing a print routine in VBA. 
A

```
PrintOut , , , True
```

statement will print the sheet for you;
add whatever other actions you want (e.g., incrementing a counter). 
(You just have to remember to print *using this macro*.) 
The fourth parameter to `PrintOut` is *Preview*, set to `True`
to have Microsoft Excel invoke print preview before printing the sheet
(thus giving you the option to cancel)
or `False` (or omitted) to print the sheet immediately, unconditionally.

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)
for information on, well, you know.