# How do I get a number that increments for every document printed?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, microsoft-word-2013

I would like a unique, increment, number on each document printed document. I need these numbers to start at, say, 83, for the first document.

For bonus points, I plan on printing two A5 documents on one A4 page, so it is the actual number of documents printed, not just the two print jobs that must be counted.

Comment: "bonus points"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229077/how-to-catch-print-jobs-in-c-sharp-net may be helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counter in Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/922870/counter-in-excel)

Comment: @Xavierjazz Don't take every word you read so seriously. All I meant was that I have an extra question. In many competitions, you win "bonus points" by answering an extra question or performing an extra task.

Comment: Something like `Get-WMIObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue |
 Select Name, @{Expression={$_.jobs};Label="CurrentJobs"}, TotalJobsPrinted, JobErrors`?  _Hint_ from [here](https://learn-powershell.net/2010/11/21/viewing-print-queue-statistics-with-powershell/). You can do a [little command](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5593448/3569208) to do it too.