# How do I force Excel to always type purple text?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm making changes to a large Excel worksheet, and every change I make needs to be in purple text. Right now, I'm typing the change and then clicking purple text.

Is there a way to force Excel to always type purple? Or is there a keyboard shortcut I can use to apply the purple text without taking my hands off the keyboard?

I'm not asking how to change the keyboard shortcuts. I need to end up with a clean sheet (no Track Changes still visible) with the cells that I've changed in purple text. I'm not changing every cell, just about 30% of them.

Comment: If all cells needs to be purple text, just select all cells, and press the purple text tool.

Comment: LPChips, Im not changing every cell, just certain cells. about 30% of the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If VBA is a valid solution: You can use the [`Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event to automatically colorize your cell if you change values.

<sub>Example to [change text color to purple](http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/colors.php)</sub>

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Font.ColorIndex = 7
End Sub
```

<sub>Example to change backcolor to red</sub>

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: This might do the trick, How do i apply that code to my worksheet?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/q/801609/76571

Comment: @Cooldog117 Press ALT+F11 to open the VBA editor. Paste the 3 lines of code under `sheet1`. That's it. try it by changing some values on sheet 1

Answer (score 1):

Try `Review > Track Changes` for a similar and minimally invasive effect.

Comment: I need to end up with a Clean sheet (no track changes still visable) with the cells that i've changed in purple text.

Answer (score 0):

You can either just select all cells and apply the appropriate formatting, or create a style (Main Tools on the ribboon), for instance by creating (duplicating) a new one or modifying an existing one.

If you need just some cells formatted this way, you can do some research on so-called conditional formatting. It's a handy function in Excel that allows you make very easy scripts that enable you to format every second row, any cell with a specific (type of) value etc. – basically anything you want. It's very easy to google out tutorials or ready-to-use formulas that you could copy-paste with one or two modifications.