# Need to count the amount of times -1 appears above a certain cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following Excel Spreadsheet -

```
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     6461735 Khanyile;Florence   Success      1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     6765475 Manana;Witness      Success      1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     6765459 Kubheka;Nomusa      Success      1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     -1                          Not Matched  1000
Hy Newcastle 042216     1905465 Nkosi;Xolani        Success      1000
```

What I need to do is a count of how many times -1 appears above each person. I've tried a pivot, but then it groups the same employees together and I need it to do the count individually. So for

Kubheka;Nomusa it will be 3,
Khanyile;Florence it will be 1, etc.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can do it either with a helper column (changing it's value when name column changes from a name to -1) and a pivot, or you can use array formulas which do the same without extra column but the formula is much more complex, which one would you prefer?

Comment: Hey Máté - first one sounds good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This VBa script does it

```
Option Explicit

Sub walkThePlank()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim total As Integer
total = 0
Do While (Range("D" & row).Value <> "")

    Dim val As String
    val = Range("D" & row).Value

    If (val = "-1") Then
        total = total + 1
    Else
        Range("G" & row).Value = total
        total = 0
    End If


row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Before it is run

[image]

And after

[image]

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, inser a *module* on the worknook and paste this on the right side:

```
Public Function countNegatives(name As Range)
    countNegatives = 0
    If name <> "-1" Then
        therow = name.Row
        thecolumn = name.Column
    End If
    endrow = False
    counter = 0
    While endrow = False
        If therow > 1 Then
            therow = therow - 1
            If Cells(therow, thecolumn) = -1 Then
                counter = counter + 1
            Else
                endrow = True
            End If
        Else
            endrow = True
        End If
    Wend
    countNegatives = counter
End Function
```

On the worksheet, on cell G2 put `=countNegatives(D2)` and you will have the result.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without VBA:

1. Create a helper column with this formula:   `=IF(C2=-1,"",COUNTIF($C1:C$2,-1)-SUM($G1:G$2))`
2. Add pivot table with names and the helper column (or you may even filter your original range to exclude rows without names.

[image]