# Return number corresponding to entry within array in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of names and I wish to create a column next to this indicating what number of entry in the list every given name is. An example of what I am trying to achieve, the column entitled "ENTRY", is below,:

```
INDEX NAME    ENTRY
1     MIKE    1
2     JANE    1
3     JANE    2
4     JANE    3
5     LANA    1
6     MIKE    2
7     JEREMY  1
8     CLIVE   1
9     JANE    4
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think your question is clear, so +1, however, you don't explain why you want this...so I'm making a few assumptions and as such I don't feel you can do this without VBa. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBa does what you want.

Remember to take a back up fo the file first, there is no undo function

```
Option Explicit
Sub EeekPirates()

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2                          'Ah hoy cap'ain, enter the startRow

Dim entryColumn As String
entryColumn = "C"                     'Enter the entry column so we can place the gold...

Dim nameColumn As String
nameColumn = "B"                      'Enter the name column so we know the sea dogs name

'aye aye cap'ain, we'll start now. Touch any of the below and we'll feed ye to the sharks

Dim realStartRow As Integer
realStartRow = startRow


Dim innerRow As Integer
innerRow = startRow
Do While (Range(nameColumn & startRow).Value <> "")
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
Dim name As String
name = Range(nameColumn & startRow).Value
    Do While (innerRow - 1 < startRow)
        If (Range(nameColumn & innerRow).Value = name) Then
            count = count + 1
        End If

        innerRow = innerRow + 1
    Loop
    Range(entryColumn & startRow).Value = count
    innerRow = realStartRow
    startRow = startRow + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

And a screen shot of what it looks like after the VBa is executed

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Excellent. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Without *VBA*

In **C2** enter **1**, in **C3** enter:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B3,B3)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: +1 better answer than mine

Comment: @Dave Your answer is also good!

Comment: Excellent. This also works. I'll leave answer as is but will mark this up when I have sufficient reputation. Many thanks for your help.