# How to split text with a comma delimiter in a lined cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I need to split an address into rows for postage.
In Tab 1 I have my members details
In Tab 2 I have my Invoice that we mail out.

In Tab 2 I run a `VLOOKUP` function to pull the member's details from Tab 1

```
PO Box 211, Alberton, 1450
```

Now the problem starts...

Normal "Text to Columns" can't be used due to the formula bar showing the `VLOOKUP` formula instead of the actual address.

```
=IF(F7=""," ",VLOOKUP(F7,'Permanente en Jaarlede'!B4:Y2063,24,FALSE))
```

How do I change my address from:

`PO Box 211, Alberton, 1450` to:

```
PO Box 211
Alberton
1450
```

when the text is the result of a formula, not just a bare value?

Comment: I guess you want an excel worksheet instead of a VBa?

Comment: That's correct yes.... If possible?

Comment: Come to think Dave, if a VBa script in a button can perform this task? It will also help i imagine?

Comment: Yup! This can be done easily with VBa and the code will be small so easy to maintain and understand

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with Excel Formulae but this VBa will do it.

First thing, is take a back up of your file before running it.

It will take the value of A1 and split it over multiple lines

```
Public Function Addy(cellToLookup As String)

Dim result As String
result = Range(cellToLookup).Value

Dim splitty() As String
splitty = Split(result, ",")

Dim i As Integer
i = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(splitty)

Range("B" & i + 1).Value = splitty(i)   'update for start row. EG, change B to col, and the +1 to +15 (if you want it to start on row 15)

Next i

End Function
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

What isn't clear form your question is, how many rows you will need and if you need to perform this multiple times etc but, this hopefully can get you going. You may need to perform the look up with VBa too, which should be easy enough.

Comment: The longest address line consist of 5 values.

Comment: So it needs to be broken up and split into 5 rows

Comment: And yes, I have over 49000 members and thus needed the vlookup to import each member's details to the Invoice by only typing in their Member ID Number

Comment: Thanks for helping Dave, We close up shop now. I will continue tomorrow morning and look at your responses. Be safe

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute the `", "` with `"CHAR(10)"`.

Make sure you have line wrapping (Wrap Text) enabled for the cell with multiple rows:

If A1 looked like `PO Box 211, Alberton, 1450`, in your new cell use:

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",CHAR(10))`.

The new cell would look like:

```
PO Box 211
Alberton
1450
```

reference: [substitute-a-comma-with-a-break-link-in-a-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856501/substitute-a-comma-with-a-break-link-in-a-cell)

Comment: I just tried your formula, but all it does is remove the comma, the address stil stays in in row?

Comment: I get back: "PO Box 211Alberton1450" in one roe instead of spliiting into 3 rows?

Comment: I don't think Line Wrapping is a real solution, what if you had the following My Address, My, My, And Last Line, --- As you can see, it would probably split on 3 lines instead of 4

Comment: Dave, How would the code look like for that?

Comment: Problem solved!! After placing the formula, the column width and cell formatting needs to be changed to Wrap Text. Thanks for the help guys! Enjoy the weekend!

Comment: @JacquesSmit, glad it worked for you.