# Highlight Duplicate Rows (not cells)

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, duplicate

I need to highlight duplicate rows in my Excel 2013 sheet. I can highlight duplicate cell values within rows, using "Highlight --> Duplicate" method, but what i'm trying to do is to highlight the rows as a whole that are duplicates. If only one cell is different for that row then it's not considered duplicate in my case.

Example:

```
Name    Task     Phone Number
A       Do 1     12345
B       Do 1     12345
A       Do 2     12345
B       Do 1     12345
```

For the above table, only rows 2 and 4 should be highlighted.

Comment: `If only one cell is different for that row then it's not considered duplicate in my case.` Then what is considered a dupe? This can be solved using VBa

Comment: A row is considered a duplicate if exists another row that is exactly equivalent to it, it has a replica of the first rows cells. Please check the example i added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask to highlight the rows but I'm guessing this *may* be problematic (although you don't describe why you want this). Assuming you have 10 rows, and many of those match other rows, your worksheet will look like

[image]

The issue is you have no idea which row matches what row!

You will also have the issue when you next run the script, the highlight will persist.

As such, I offer a solution with an extra column of information (screen shot below):

```
Sub WalkThePlank()

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2                 'Update this to lead us to the treasure

Dim row As Integer
row = startRow

Do While (Range("A" & row).Value <> "")

    Dim innerRow As Integer
    innerRow = row + 1

    Dim name As String
    Dim task As String
    Dim phone As String

    name = Range("A" & row).Value
    task = Range("B" & row).Value
    phone = Range("C" & row).Value

    Do While (Range("A" & innerRow).Value <> "")


        If (Range("A" & innerRow).Value = name And Range("B" & innerRow).Value = task And Range("C" & innerRow).Value = phone) Then
            Range("D" & row).Value = Range("D" & row).Value & innerRow & ", "
            Range("D" & innerRow).Value = Range("D" & innerRow).Value & row & ", "
            'Rows(row).Interior.ColorIndex = 6      'UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT HIGHLIGHTING

            'Rows(innerRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 6      'UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU WANT HIGHLIGHTING
        End If

    innerRow = innerRow + 1
    Loop

    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

This is what it does

[image]

Do this on a copy of your file - there is no undo feature!

Note in the code there are 2 lines showing you which line to uncomment (remove the first `'` on those lines and they will highlight)

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)