# Excel data numbering

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a series of data in excel as under

```
ARG2755-NNL4W
BBF1732-NNM4WF
BES0542-NNM4W
BES0542-NNM4W
BES0542-NNM4W
BES0542-NNM4W
BES0542-NNM4W
BES0542-NNM4W
BRA0743-NNM4VF
BRA1650-NNM4TK
BRA1919-NNO1PK
BRA1919-NNO1WK
BRA1920-NNL4VK
BRA1920-NNL4VK
BRB0939-NNL4WF
BRB1625-NNL4WK
BRB1625-NNL4WK
```

I want to number it as under:

```
1   ARG2755-NNL4W
2   BBF1732-NNM4WF
3   BES0542-NNM4W
    BES0542-NNM4W
    BES0542-NNM4W
    BES0542-NNM4W
    BES0542-NNM4W
    BES0542-NNM4W
4   BRA0743-NNM4VF
5   BRA1650-NNM4TK
6   BRA1919-NNO1PK
7   BRA1919-NNO1WK
8   BRA1920-NNL4VK
    BRA1920-NNL4VK
9   BRB0939-NNL4WF
10  BRB1625-NNL4WK
    BRB1625-NNL4WK
```

Please help

Comment: Do you need the blanks, or would it be acceptable to show tied values? Also what have you tried?

Comment: @NIMISHAN, can you expand on your comment, because as it is, it's not very helpful (when you consider there are already 2 answers, none of which use either approach you've suggested) :( If you know how to to do it please share because you may have a better solution than the answers posted :)

Answer (score 4):

With data in column **B**, in **A1** enter:

```
1
```

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(B2=B1,"",1+MAX($A$1:A1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: Well that's much neater. +1

Answer (score 3):

Assuming columns are A and B, put a `1` in column `A1`, then put this formula in `A2` and drag it down

`=IF(NOT(B2=B1),INDEX($A$1:A1,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$1:A1))+1,"")`

This works by:

`=IF(NOT(B2=B1)...` - Compares cell B2 to B1. If they don't match...

`INDEX($A$1:A1,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$1:A1))+1` - This finds the last number from `A1` (Fixed), to A1 (Variable), and adds 1 to it. The $'s are needed to make sure it's always comparing from A1, down to the cell just before it. Otherwise:

`"")` - Just return a blank string.

[image]

Comment: `INDEX($A$1:A1,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,$A$1:A1))+1` - See, when comparing VBa to this compact nightmare, VBa seems so much clearer. Regardless, I feel your answer is better than mine as it is with worksheet formula so +1 :)

Comment: @Dave Most formulas feel horribly hacky. But they are easier for the end user usually. I like yours for ease of reading, definitely. Even if there was just a way to indent formulas or something, rather than having nests of hundreds of brackets on a single line...

Comment: @Dave And I'm sure that 9.999999999etc part could be like, 1000, but this way prevents it breaking if the number is too high.

Answer (score 2):

This VBA does it. Do this on a copy of your workbook as there is no undo option.

Also note, you can set some values at the start of the code

```
Option Explicit
Sub SailMeHearties()

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Dim col As String
col = "B"

Dim colOfNumber As String
colOfNumber = "A"

' LEAVE THE CODE BELOW ALONE OR WALK THE PLANK

Range(colOfNumber + ":" + colOfNumber).Clear
Range(colOfNumber & row).Value = 1

Dim startNumber As Integer
startNumber = 2

row = row + 1

Do While Range(col & row).Value <> ""

    If (Range(col & row).Value <> Range(col & row - 1).Value) Then
        Range(colOfNumber & row).Value = startNumber
        startNumber = startNumber + 1
    End If
    row = row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Also see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)