# Apply "Alternating case" to a document?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, microsoft-word-2007

Is there any way to convert a document in one word upper and one lower case sequentially?  For example, I write a line "HOW ARE YOU I AM FINE" and this will convert into "HoW aRe YoU i Am FiNe".

Comment: Are you asking to convert text in MS Word to capitalize every other letter of a sentence automatically?

Comment: Check out the VBA suggestion from G-Man. What you want to do is rather odd. Why would the writer of a Word Processor application bother offering this feature? Just write some code yourself in (for example) VBA, C#, C++, Delphi, etc. You can download Visual Studio 2008 or 2012 (Express) for free. The coding itself takes a bit of time to get into but once you get going you can achieve all many of fun and whacky things! :o)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a VBA routine that will do what you describe:

```
Sub Alternate_case()

    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^$"
        .Forward = True
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        Do While True
            .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop
            If Not .Found Then Exit Do
            Selection.Range.Case = wdUpperCase
            .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop
            If Not .Found Then Exit Do
            Selection.Range.Case = wdLowerCase
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Selection.HomeKey` statement is equivalent
to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>;
it jumps to the beginning of the document. 
Delete it if you just want to start wherever you are
when you invoke the routine. 
The next dozen lines set up a case-insensitive, non-wildcarded,
forward search for a letter (`Text = "^$"`). 
(You may be able to get away with deleting the `….ClearFormatting` lines
and the `… = False` lines,
as these just explicitly establish the default parameters.)

The `Do While True` block is an "infinite loop"
that stops after it finds the last letter in the document. 
It executes the configured search (for a letter)
without wraparound to the beginning of the document (`Wrap:=wdFindStop`);
if it fails (`Not .Found`), it terminates the loop (`Exit Do`),
otherwise it proceeds to capitalize the selected letter and search again. 
On the next search, if successful, it sets the letter to lower case,
and so on.

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/354511) for general information
on how to use VBA in Microsoft Word (and Excel, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

This is <strike>indeed</strike> nearly possible.  Just select the option you want using the  capitlization font button.

[image]

Here is a full description of what you must do.

> On the **Home** tab, in the **Font** group, click **Change
>   Case** [image], and then click the
>   capitalization option that you want.

You can also select text then perform the keyboard shortcut

> To change case by using a keyboard shortcut, press **SHIFT+F3** until
>   the style you want — title case, all caps, or lowercase — is selected.

[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-capitalization-of-text-9e3a6b90-5aa4-4fe9-85da-2852605c57af)

Which is exactly what you should do to your question.  You can even copy and paste the quoted text to do exactly that.

> Hey guys i have a question that is there any way to convert a document
>   in one word upper and one lower case sequentially for example i write
>   a line "how are you i am fine" and this will convert into "HoW aRe YoU
>   i Am FiNe"

Comment: I just realized the output would not exactly be what you want.  It is the best you can do within Word though without writing a VBA macro.