# Bitwise Operations Missing? (Excel for Mac 2011)

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

According to the relevant 
[Microsoft Support page on the BITAND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/BITAND-function-8a2be3d7-91c3-4b48-9517-64548008563a), I should have access to it, as I am running Excel for Mac 2011 (with the latest updates installed):

"APPLIES TO: Excel 2016, Excel 2013, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel for Mac 2011",

When when I try to use it, e.g. by entering "=BITAND(127,8)" I get the dreaded "#NAME?", showing that it is not in fact recognized.  It does not appear as an auto-complete option while typing, in fact entering just "=BIT" generates no autocomplete suggestions.

The Microsoft Support page doesn't say anything about needing to install additional add-in packages, although I know that's sometimes an issue.  (Note: apparently it was required in 2008 as [this link suggests](http://www.edn.com/design/other/4325407/Perform-bitwise-operation-in-Excel-spreadsheets), but nothing for the 2011 version.)

Can anyone offer a suggestion to get this working?

Alternatively, I just want to obtain a decimal-to-binary conversion but unlike DEC2BIN I don't want a string of 1's and 0's in the same cell, rather I want each bit value to end up in its own cell.  Perhaps parsing the DEC2BIN string would get the job done.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an English version of Excel? Every time when I'm using a localized version, I'm surprised by Microsoft having translated the function names: [Dutch](https://support.office.com/nl-nl/article/BITAND-function-8a2be3d7-91c3-4b48-9517-64548008563a), [German](https://support.office.com/de-de/article/BITAND-function-8a2be3d7-91c3-4b48-9517-64548008563a), [French](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/BITAND-function-8a2be3d7-91c3-4b48-9517-64548008563a)...

Comment: You can “parse” the return value of `DEC2BIN(A1,8)` with `MID(DEC2BIN(A1,8), 1, 1)`, `MID(DEC2BIN(A1,8), 2, 1)`, …, `MID(DEC2BIN(A1,8), 8, 1)`.

Comment: Using English the English version,   Yea, just ended up parsing DEC2BIN, noticed @G-man's comment afterward.   Will still leave the question up for the future,  in case someone comes up with a solution that enables BITAND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA includes *operators* `AND` and `OR`,
so you can create user-defined functions as follows:

```
Function Band(arg1, arg2)
    Band = arg1 And arg2
End Function

Function Bor(arg1, arg2)
    Bor = arg1 Or arg2
End Function
```

You can then call these, e.g., `=Band(127,8)`, from cells.

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988) for general information.