# Excel - Formula to return a single value for each unique identifier

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: My Excel table]

What I have:
A column that contains year plus week number which serves as a unique time identifier for my data, and a column that contains a value. Amount of rows varies. As you can see, Value is identical for every row that has the same YEAR+WEEKNUM.

What I need:
To to return a single value for every YEAR+WEEKNUM - and these values have to appear in the C column. I cannot just filter unique values, since different weeks sometimes have the same values.

Comment: it seems to be a typical use of a pivot table, have you tried it already?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Mate - Yes, a pivot table worked for me, though I would like to know a way to accomplish the same using just a formula.
CharlieRB - Unfortunately I do not even know how to find a starting point to create such a formula, I've seen multiple tutorial on formulae that return unique values, but not one that would fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And here is the non-VBA equivalent.  In **D2** enter:

```
2
```

In **D3** enter:

```
=IF(A3=A2,"",1+MAX($D$1:D2))
```

and copy down.  Then in **C2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROW(),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

***Note:***

This approach does not use array formulas or volatile functions.  It takes advantage of the fact that column **A**'s data is organized into groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had a few minutes to kill so I offer a VBa solution. You didn't ask for VBa but as there is currently no other solution it may suffice. I suspect @MateJuhasz solution of a pivot table is best but not sure if that classifies as a worksheet formula (I suspect not)

```
Sub WalkThePlank()

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 2

Dim resultRow As Integer
resultRow = 1

Dim resultCol As String
resultCol = "C"

Dim prev As String
prev = ""

Do While Range("A" & startRow).Value <> ""
    Dim v As String
    v = Range("A" & startRow).Value

    If (prev <> v) Then
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
        prev = v
    End If

    Range("C" & resultRow).Value = Range("B" & startRow).Value

    startRow = startRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Remember there is no undo option in VBa so take a back up first

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)