# How can I sum with partial parts of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Let's say I have a spreadsheet look like this.

```
A |B
----------------
1 |1.0 2016-05-07
2 |0.5 2016-04-12
3 |x.y yyyy-MM-dd
```

How can I sum those first values(`1.0`, `0.5`)?

Comment: Are the numbers all formatted as #.# followed by space? Are you trying to get the sum in a cell value with a formula or use VBA macro?

Comment: @dbmitch Yes all values are `#.#`. And I want to know how to `=SUM(...)`.

Comment: I assume you can't spilt them into different cells?

Comment: @Dave I wish I can.

Comment: In that case use left and sum...  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-LEFTB-functions-9203d2d2-7960-479b-84c6-1ea52b99640c

Comment: @Dave You're right. And how can I sum of all cells which each is `LEFT`ed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array formula like the following:

**=SUMPRODUCT(1*LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))**
where A1:A3 is the column of your data, and you have always a space between numbers and date, the formula finds the first space and read the number on the left and use Ctrl + Shift + Enter instead of 'Enter' for array formula, sumproduct will add the numbers.
In case your Data does not start always with numbers you can use:
**=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(VALUE(LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1))),1*LEFT(A1:A3,FIND(" ",A1,1)-1),0))**

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT - MY MISTAKE - YOU CAN DO IT WITH a basic Excel functions - see
>   answer!

Here's another way using a VBA module, and custom public function

Insert this in VBA Code

```
Public Function SumLeftData(rgeData As Range) As Double

    Dim celVal  As Object

    For Each celVal In rgeData.Cells
        SumLeftData = SumLeftData + Left(celVal, 3)
    Next

End Function
```

For your example, you would then insert formula in cell C3 (or wherever)
that `=SumLeftData(B1:B3)`

**NOTE**

> Make sure it's in Module1 - not in Workbook code

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)