# Need to filter out some names from a list of Total names

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a list of names.
I need to separate the names which contains characters `g,j,p,q,y`.
The names can start with `G,J,P,Q,Y` i.e the characters as first letter. But the characters g,j,p,q,y shouldn't be in any other part of the name.

Please help me.

Ex: need to filter out names like
Cathy, Deejay, Diego, Gray etc

Exceptions:
Gina, Gracie, Jane, Priscilla, etc

Comment: Your question is really messy. Please explain for each name why do you need to exclude / not exclude it.

Comment: if you see the name Cathy, y is in the last position. In Deejay j and y are in 4th and 6th positions. In Diego g is in the 4th position same goes with Gray so i need to filter out such names.

In names Gina, Grace G is in the first position. In Jane J is in the first position and in Priscilla P is in the first position so they can be in the list.

I have a list of 60k plus names.

Comment: What is filter out? Do you mean delete? Is it a name per cell? Is it only ever a single name in the cell?

Comment: I mean to copy those to a different sheet.
Yes one name per cell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you do this with a worksheet formula, but as you've not got an answer this VBa will do it

```
Option Explicit
Sub WalkThePlank()

Dim column As String
column = "A"                      'Update this to ye starting col

Dim row As Integer
row = 1                             'Aye cap'an, this be your first row

Dim badLetters As String
badLetters = "gjpqy"               'piracy! Enter the scurvy seadog letters you don't want as a complete word

'don't touch below or be fed to the sharks

Do While Range(column & row).Value <> ""

    Dim name As String
    name = Range(column & row).Value

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(badLetters)
        Dim c As String
        c = Mid(badLetters, i + 1, 1)
        If InStr(1, name, c) > 0 And c <> "" Then
            Range(column & row).Value = ""
            Exit For
        End If


    Next i

    row = row + 1

Loop    
End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Remember, there is no undo function so save a copy first!!

Before

[image]

After

[image]