# Change adjacent cell where a cell matches a certain value

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

If I have the following table:

```
------------------
| X | helloworld |
------------------
| X | random1234 |
------------------
| X | random5678 |
------------------
| X | helloworld |
------------------
| X | random9123 |
------------------
```

How can I set the value of the first cell to the *left* of each occurence of `helloworld` to `Y`?

After processing, I would expect the above example to be:

```
------------------
| Y | helloworld |
------------------
| X | random1234 |
------------------
| X | random5678 |
------------------
| Y | helloworld |
------------------
| X | random9123 |
------------------
```

To clarify, my spreadsheet contains thousands of these occurrences, I'm looking for a bulk operation, in pseudocode:

```
for every row:
    if column_B = 'helloworld':
        column_A = 'X'
    if column_B = 'random':
        column_A = ...
```

Comment: If the only values in first column are X & Y you can put a simple IF function in that column checking value of adjacent cell. =IF(B1="helloworld","Y","X"). Put this formula in cell A1 and drag (copy) it down all the way

Comment: @pat2015 actually that was just an example, the spreadsheet has thousands of rows, and the first column has ~50 possible values (they're actually words, not characters). Your solution would likely work but it sounds ill-suited to write an if statement for ~50 values in those cells. It may be the only way though.

Comment: You can copy column A to column C and use C as helper column. Formula in A1 then becomes =IF(B1="helloworld","Y",C1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This VBa does it.

There is no option to undo, so take a back up first!

```
Sub WalkThePlank()

Dim updateColumn As String
updateColumn = "A"           'update this ye filthy seadog if needed! This be the first column

Dim contentColumn As String
contentColumn = "B"         'aye, scrub the deck and update if the "helloworld" isn't in column B

Dim startRow As Integer
startRow = 1                  'enter the start row or be fed to the sharks  

Do While (Range(contentColumn & startRow).Value <> "")

    Dim val As String
    val = Range(contentColumn & startRow).Value

    Select Case val

    Case "helloworld"
        Range(updateColumn & startRow).Value = "Y"

    Case Else
        Range(updateColumn & startRow).Value = "X" ' This is the "default value

    End Select        

    startRow = startRow + 1

Loop    

End Sub
```

To add another case, such as if the search word was Goodbyeworld, update the code to

```
    Select Case val

    Case "helloworld"
        Range(updateColumn & startRow).Value = "Y"

    Case "Goodbyeworld" ' CASE SENSITIVE!!!!
        Range(updateColumn & startRow).Value = "A"

    Case Else
        Range(updateColumn & startRow).Value = "X" ' This is the "default value

    End Select
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Before
[image]

After
[image]