# Is it possible for a formula to automatically update to new data in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I am inputting dated amounts into a single column. The newest data will then be divided by a constant that I have at the top of the page. I would like the formula of "newest amount" divided by "constant" to automatically update when I input new data.

Here is a simple setup of what I mean:

[image: example worksheet]

As I have it now the formula would read `=(B5/$D$2)`

Then when I add data to B6, I must manually change to formula to reflect that.

**Is it possible when I add data to B6, B7, and so on that the formula can adjust automatically?**

Edit for clarity: I would want to formula to adjust based on cell position alone, not related to a modification time/date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want it (as per your example) to be based upon the last value in B column you can use

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))),B:B)
```

So your formula would be

```
=(LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(B:B))),B:B))/$D$2
```

This has many issues, if you made a change mid way through your B column then you'd have still do it manually!

If you want it to fire based upon the most recent row you've edited, then you'd need to use VBa's `Worksheet_Change` event

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Column = 2) Then
        Range("E2").Value = Range("D2").Value / Target.Value
    End If    
End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Please remember, there is no undo with VBa, so take a back up first and make sure you save the file as a Macro enabled file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))/$D$2
```

The INDEX/MATCH will return the value in the last cell in column B that has a number in it.  So as numbers are added to column B the reference will change automatically to the last number.

[image]