# Extract all the numbers from single excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Given an excel sheet with mixed number and text.

ES:

```
123|text|11
-----------
hi |  75| 1
```

How can I scan all the sheet and extract just the numbers in a single column?

```
123|
----
 75|
----
 11|
----
  1|
```

I prefer not to use VBA, order is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a formula:

```
 =IFERROR(LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(A$1:C$3),A$1:C$3),ROW()),"")
```

This lists the numbers from large to small:

[image]

This is an array formula, so it must be entered with CTRL-Shift Enter, rather than just Enter.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

To scan the whole sheet, change the ranges in the IF statement to $1:$1048576.  But you'll need to exclude the column you're listing the numbers in.  So you could list in Column A and use B$1:XFD$1048576. (This is for Excel after 2007).

Comment: Whoa, I needed 20 minutes to understand it.

Comment: Sorry, I usually write an explanation, but I had to go look at the eclipse. :-D

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the use case here but the logic I'd suggest is (without using VBa) is to copy each column into a single long column, then simply sort alphabetically!

So it starts off as

[image]

Copy and paste to a single column

[image]

Add a new row and a heading title click on `Filter` (in the `Data` ribbon, `Sort and Filter` tab)

Sort smallest to largest

[image]

Simply delete the other rows!

If copying all the columns into a single column is too time consuming then see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480227/how-to-consolidate-data-from-multiple-excel-columns-all-into-one-column

```
Sub MakeOneColumn()

    Dim vaCells As Variant
    Dim vOutput() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lRow As Long

    If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
        If Selection.Count > 1 Then
            If Selection.Count <= Selection.Parent.Rows.Count Then
                vaCells = Selection.Value

                ReDim vOutput(1 To UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)

                For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                    For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
                        If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                            lRow = lRow + 1
                            vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
                        End If
                    Next i
                Next j

                Selection.ClearContents
                Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lRow).Value = vOutput
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Comment: I can also use a ISNUMBER but still this approach is too manual :(
I need to scan all the sheet...

Comment: You have not defined that in your question though...

Comment: I'm sorry i'll update the question