# Saving Excel sheet as JSON file

Tags: microsoft-excel, json

Is there a simple way to convert a simple excel sheet to a JSON file?

For example the source sheet could look like:

```
   A           B
1 firstName   age
2 Alice       22
3 Bob         33
```

and the saved JSON:

```
[{firstName: 'Alice', age: 22}, {firstName: 'Bob', age: 33}]
```

Comment: Googling to "table to json" gives you several solutions, e.g. [this](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've combined [jcbermu’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1249898/150988#1249918)
and [JanHudecek’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/1249898/150988#1323957)
with a UTF-8 version ([snippets found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2525196))
which keeps accents and other Unicode goodness.

It saves the file beside the active workbook file but with the `.json` file extension. It's fast. It can be easily formatted in VS Code (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

To use it, hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to get to the VBA code editor, open the code for your active worksheet, then paste it into the code window. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run.

```
Public Sub tojson()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    jsonFilename = fso.GetBaseName(ActiveWorkbook.Name) & ".json"
    fullFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & jsonFilename

    Dim fileStream As Object
    Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fileStream.Type = 2 'Specify stream type - we want To save text/string data.
    fileStream.Charset = "utf-8" 'Specify charset For the source text data.
    fileStream.Open 'Open the stream And write binary data To the object

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)

    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    fileStream.WriteText "["
    dq = """"
    escapedDq = "\"""
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                fileStream.WriteText "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = Replace(wks.Cells(j, i), dq, escapedDq)
            fileStream.WriteText dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                fileStream.WriteText ","
            End If
        Next i
        fileStream.WriteText "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            fileStream.WriteText ","
        End If
    Next j
    fileStream.WriteText "]"
    fileStream.SaveToFile fullFilePath, 2 'Save binary data To disk
    a = MsgBox("Saved to " & fullFilePath, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Comment: For general advice on using VBA, see [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the script to actually finish before you're a pensioner, I suggest writing to the output file immediately instead of concatenating the string var:

```
Public Sub tojson()
    savename = "exportedxls.json"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    Print #1, "["
    dq = """"
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                Print #1, "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            Print #1, dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                Print #1, ","
            End If
        Next i
        Print #1, "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            Print #1, ","
        End If
    Next j
    Print #1, "]"
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This VBA code will work :

```
Public Sub tojson()
    savename = "exportedxls.json"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    json = "["
    dq = """"
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                json = json & "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                json = json & ","
            End If
        Next i
        json = json & "}"
        If j <> lrow Then
            json = json & ","
        End If
    Next j
    json = json & "]"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, json
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Open VBA /Macros with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

On the left side double click on The worksheet, on the right side paste the code.

Set the variable `savename` to the name that you want for the json file and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

1. save as csv
2. convert to json with [mlr](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/file-formats.html)

   mlr --icsv --ifs ';' --ojson cat exported.csv > out.json

If you want to transform the jsonfile. You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
jq -s '[.[]|{newfieldname: .oldone, "phone": "123"}]' out.json > transformed.json
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple one off conversion to JSON there's websites for this.

I've used this with good results:
https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-json.htm

Answer (score 0):

I used this converter for similar task: names:

```
http://www.whiterocksoftware.com/2021/08/convert-xlsx-excel-file.html?q=excel+to+json#ExcelToJson
```

converter produced json file  with array of entities and uses first row as field