# Excel table to JSON with additional fields from other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, json

I had gone through 
[Saving Excel sheet as JSON file](https://superuser.com/questions/1249898/saving-excel-sheet-as-json-file?newreg=bfdfa247f5874384aadbf0c35190e9c9), which helped me to convert EXCEL table to JSON but I wish to add some additional fields to this JSON file.

[image]

I am asking the following information In **first worksheet**

1. Your ID           : A001
2. Name              : My NAME
3. List item         : Oct-2018

---

[**My 2nd Sheet**]

This information  will be  common for data entered in  2nd sheet

---

While creating JSON file I want to Add "Automatically" the following 3 fields (accepted in Sheet 1) in each record for JSON I am creating from Sheet2

1. Your ID           : A001
2. Name              : My NAME
3. List item         : Oct-2018

---

I am using following VBA code to create JSON

```
Public Sub xls2json()
    savename = "xls2json.json"
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(2)
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(4, i) 'titles are taken from this row
    Next i
    json = "["
    dq = """"
    For J = 5 To lrow ' data picked from this row onwards
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            If i = 1 Then
                json = json & "{"
            End If
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(J, i)
            json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
            If i <> lcolumn Then
                json = json & ","
            End If
        Next i
        json = json & "}"
        If J <> lrow Then
             json = json & ","
        End If
     Next J
    json = json & "]"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Print #1, json
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what we're looking at.  What is the original worksheet?  The description of sheet2 is circular.  Where does data get added, field orderwise?  What should the resulting file look like?  Why not just add the fields in Excel and then convert to JSON?  What, exactly, is the difficulty holding you up?

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you have JSON files for sheel1 and sheet2 and want to add columns from sheet2 to sheet1. Something like below.

```
0 > cat file1.json
[
  {
    "firstName": "Alice",
    "age": 22
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Bob",
    "age": 33
  }
]
0 > cat file2.json
[
  {
    "fullName": "Alice Alice"
  },
  {
    "fullName": "Bob Bob"
  }
]
```

to get something like ...

```
0 > python3 ./bla.py file1.json file2.json
[
    {
        "firstName": "Alice",
        "age": 22,
        "fullName": "Alice Alice"
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "age": 33,
        "fullName": "Bob Bob"
    }
]
```

Following Python code should work

```
import json, sys


def main():
    '''The Main'''

    data1 = json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))
    data2 = json.load(open(sys.argv[2]))

    assert (len(data1) == len(data2)), "Number of rows not equal"

    for i in range(len(data1)):
        for k in data2[i].keys():
            data1[i][k] = data2[i][k]

    print(json.dumps(data1, indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

HTH

Krishna

Comment: What you have conclude is 100% correct. I am using VBA code