# Automatically add spaces between words in a Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, text-editors, text-editing, text-formatting

I have a Word document about 200 pages. The text I pasted from a PDF lost it's spaces for some reason. How do I fix this?

Comment: When you pasted the text in from the .PDF, did you right-click and Paste Special, selecting a specific paste operation?

Comment: I think you need a better way (than copy/paste) to extract text from PDF. Can you share the PDF document so we can take a closer look?

Comment: I feel trying to fix this in Word is incorrect. The solution is to use a different program to extract the text from the PDF. Maybe you need to use an OCR or similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting but also not easy

My real answer is to suggest you fix the issue which is how the PDF was exported!

However, this VBa may get you going. There is no undo so **create a back up first**

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoIt()

Dim maxChars As Integer
maxChars = 30                         'update for the biggest word you want to check for (max characters in the word)

Dim pos As Integer
pos = 0

Dim total As Integer
total = Len(Range.Text)

Do While (pos < Len(Range.Text))

Dim s As String
s = ""

Dim wordToUse As String
wordToUse = ""
Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To maxChars

    s = s + Mid(Range.Text, pos + i, 1)

    If SpellCheck(s) = True Then
        wordToUse = s
    End If

    Next i

pos = pos + Len(wordToUse)
Dim lef As String
Dim rig As String

lef = Trim(left(Range.Text, pos))
rig = Trim(Mid(Range.Text, pos + 1))

Range.Text = Trim(lef) + " " + Trim(Replace(rig, "  ", " "))

If pos >= total Then
Exit Do
End If

Loop


End Sub


Function SpellCheck(SomeWord As String) As Boolean
'credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/10776225/1221410
    SpellCheck = Application.CheckSpelling(SomeWord)
End Function
```

The logic is simple - keeping adding characters until you find a valid word... at that point, make sure it's not part of a word (eg and exists in l*and*). Then add some white space to the end.

[How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/questions/801609/how-do-i-add-vba-in-ms-office)

Comment: Has this been tested/shown to work? I had to add/define a range first (I used Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range), after which it ran, but it seemed to insert spaces somewhat at random, rather than between known words :s

Comment: Update - the Application.Checkspelling( ) function is confused by CAPS - for reasons I won't go into, my block of un-spaced text was all caps, and converting it to all lower case made things work better!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just select all the text in the word file and click on **Clear formatting**:

[image: screenshot of tool]