# “Best Before” Date, 1 year into the future

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, calendar, date

How can I create a macro in Word for a “best before” date of one year from today that will repeat, just as today's date will in Word when invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just generating “12/23/2018”?

- Type `Date \@ “MM/dd/”=date \@ “yyyy”+1` (or copy and paste it)
  into your Word document.
  This seems to be case-insensitive
  (except in the date formats).
  And "straight quotes" ([image: straight quotes])
  and “curly quotes” ([image: curly quotes]) seem to be interchangeable.
- Select `Date \@ “MM/dd/”` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>,
  which will change it into a field. 
  It will change in appearance
  to `{ Date \@ “MM/dd/” }`
  and may have a gray background. 
  This same transformation will occur
  every time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
  Do not type any curly braces!
- Select `date \@ “yyyy”` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Select `={ date \@ “yyyy” }+1`
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
  The line should now look like:
  `{ Date \@ “MM/dd/” }{ ={ date \@ “yyyy” }+1 }`.
- Then select the entire line
  and press <kbd>F9</kbd> (***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).
- If nothing happens, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> 
  (again, ***not*** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), and that should do it.

This simply takes today’s date, formats it as “MM/dd/” (i.e., “12/23/”),
and then follows it with the current year plus one. 
(If you want another format, just change it.) 
For example, if you want "yyyy/MM/dd",
change the starting text to `=date \@ “yyyy”+1Date \@ “/MM/dd”`
and follow the same instructions
(with the difference that `MM/dd/` has been replaced with `/MM/dd`,
since you want the `/` between the year and the month,
and not after the day).

I’m not exactly sure what you mean by “save this as a macro and name it”. 
Maybe this is what you want:

- Enter `Set best_date quote =date \@ “yyyy”+1Date \@ “/MM/dd”`. 
  You might want to do this somewhere near the beginning of the document.
- Follow all the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> steps from above.
- Select `quote { ={ date \@ “yyyy” }+1 }{ Date \@ “/MM/dd” }`
  (i.e., everything from `quote` through the end of the line)
  and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Select `Set best_date { quote { ={ date \@ “yyyy” }+1 }{ Date \@ “/MM/dd” } }`
  (i.e., the entire line) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
- Repeat the last two steps from the above list
  (the ones with <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>). 
  Now, everything you’ve just done will disappear,
  but you will have defined a “bookmark” called `best_date`
  containing the next year’s date. 
  This is for all practical purposes a variable;
  it might be close enough to what you mean when you say “macro”.
- Now, anywhere in the document that you want to use the future date,
  type `best_date` and turn it into a field as described above
  (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>F9</kbd>
  and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).

`best_date` is just an arbitrary identifier. 
You can use any valid identifier, e.g., `bob_string`.

Warning: if you use this on February 29, 2020, it will display “2021/2/29”,
which is not a valid date.

---

OK, in a comment you reported that,
when you save and reopen your document, the fields appear, like

```
{ Set best_date { quote { ={ date \@ “yyyy” }+1 }{ Date \@ “/MM/dd” } } }
```

and the date does not appear. 
This is controlled by a global Word setting. 
There are at least a couple of ways of fixing it:

1. The way [Microsoft tells you](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-windows_programs/how-to-remove-default-setting-of-toggle-field/71bef6e6-cd80-41a0-b18d-ee223f88998e?auth=1) to do it:

   - Go into “Word Options”. 
     On sufficiently old versions of Word (pre-2010),
     this is accessed via the “Orb”. 
     On Word 2010 and 2013 (and higher?), it is “File” → “Options”.
   - Go to “Advanced”
     (by clicking on “Advanced” in the left column of the Options window).
   - Scroll down to the “Show document content” section.
   - Click on “Show field codes instead of their values”
     to *clear* (uncheck) the checkbox.
2. A much shorter way:

   - Press **<kbd>Alt</kbd>**+<kbd>F9</kbd>. 
     Once. 
     In any document.

You will, of course, have to do this (one of the above)
once on every machine. 
Probably once per machine *per user*. 
Or just tell your users to do it
(I recommend the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> one)
if they see field codes displayed.

I’m not sure I understand your other issue. 
Are you saying that,
if you follow the above instructions on December 28, 2017,
you will get the “2018/12/28” future date that you want,
but if you save it, and then reopen it on December 29,
it will still say “2018/12/28”, but you want it to say “2018/12/**29**”? 
This is a little trickier. 
Apparently Microsoft Word is written
to not update fields when you open a document
(possibly because it could theoretically take a long time). 
Here are two solutions to that:

1. As described [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-fields-7339a049-cb0d-4d5a-8679-97c20c643d4e) (and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/updating-all-fields-in-a-word-2010-document-on/9d0882a7-d3ea-4daa-add5-1d1482ddb5dc)),

   - select the entire document
     (the easy way to do this is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>), and
   - press <kbd>F9</kbd>.

   Unfortunately, *every* user will have to learn to do
   this *every* time they open a document (or at least each day).
2. As described [here](https://word.tips.net/T000422_Automatically_Updating_Fields_and_Links.html), write an `AutoOpen` macro that says

   ```
   Sub AutoOpen()
       With Options
           .UpdateFieldsAtPrint = True
           .UpdateLinksAtPrint = True
       End With
       ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
   End Sub
   ```

   See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/354511)
   for general information on the mechanics of this.

I recommend option 1; macros can be messy. 
But, if your users are resistant to learning new procedures,
option 2 may be a better choice for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, G-Man. I got this to work in the format provided. I would prefer it to read year/month/day, but when I try to get it to do this it prints out incorrectly as 2017 +1 then the month and day. Is there some way I can save this as a macro and name it?

Comment: I have expanded my answer  in an attempt to address your concerns.

Comment: Hello again, G-Man. My need is to have a formula which will appear on repeated uses as an actual date, so that others can use it without having to convert it. When I save the updatable future date, it either comes up next day as a formula again, or as yesterday's date in the following year with no repeatable action--the formula is lost. I need to be able to place this info into dozens of BarTender label files, so that each time one is opened, it will provide the future date one year hence: 2018/12/30, and so forth. I'm still floundering.

Comment: @Bob: Happy New Year. I have expanded my answer  in an attempt to address your concerns (again).

Comment: @Bob:  Are you still “floundering”?  If my answer works for you, please [“accept” it](/help/someone-answers "What should I do when someone answers my question?").

Comment: Hello G-Man: Yes, it did for Word Documents. I was trying to utilize this in a labeling program called BarTender, but it would not translate from Word into that medium. However, I found that BarTender itself offers a way to insert a best before date, so of course I am using that. Much thanks for your help.