# Multiple sequential substitutions using parameters in other columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In an Excel worksheet:

Column A is all filled with random text values (e.g., words / sentences)
that need to be updated.

And columns B and C contain strings that specify the changes
that need to be made to column A.
Column B is filled each cell with the old text and column C with the new text, each line corresponding to each other, this is, text in B1 need to be substituted by text C1, B2 to be changed for C2 text. In column B one of the things to substitute is a `"`.

There are no repeated values in column B.
Cells may be repeated in column C, though.
The substitutions must obey the order in which they were written.
And column D is the result.

Each cell from column A needs to pass through this substitution from B1-C1, B2-C2, B3-C3, etc., until the end of the substitution commands in columns B-C. So, before giving the final result, the text from column A will change several times, and only will show result in column D after all changes.

---

Example:

```
Cell A1: Hello!
Cell A2: How are you "John"?
Cell A3: "Nice! thanks"
```

```
Cell B1: !                           Cell C1: &
Cell B2: &                           Cell C2: .
Cell B3: "                           Cell C3:    (empty)
Cell B4: ?                           Cell C4: #
Cell B5: Nice. thanks                Cell C5: Fine, THANKS.
```

---

So Cell A1, which is `Hello!`, will be changed by B1-C1, so will be `Hello&`.
Then will change B2-C2 with changes made to the temporary result `Hello&` so will be `Hello.`. 
Then will change B3-C3 and then will do B4-C4 and then B5-C5, and nothing will happen because `"` doesn’t exist in `Hello.`.

After this, result D1 is `Hello.`.

Then it will do A2 changes B1-C1 (nothing to do), then applied to this will do B2-C2 (nothing to do), then B3-C3 which will result as `How are you John?` (i.e., the quote characters will be removed), then will do B4-C4 which will make `How are you John#`, and then B5-C5 which has nothing to be done in here.

So result D2 is `How are you John#`.

The same way, A3 value `"Nice! thanks"` will have change from B1-C1 at first, becoming `"Nice& thanks"`, then B2-C2 becoming `"Nice. thanks"`, then B3-C3 becoming `Nice. thanks` (again, the quotes will be removed), then nothing to do in B4-C4 and then B5-C5 will make it become at last `Fine, THANKS` in D3.

---

Results:

```
D1: Hello.
D2: How are you John#
D3: Fine, THANKS.
```

---

What would be the formula in column D for doing this multiple substitutions in a row obeying the line order written in columns B and C, allowing column B-C to have more than 300 lines?
(I would like a purely formula based-solution, rather than VBA, if possible.)

[image: sample data from above with processing flow illustration]

Comment: Are you able to use VBA functions, or do you need a purely formula-based solution?

Comment: Hello JRI, would like a purely formula based solution please if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you describe/illustrate with

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, B$1, C$1), B$2, C$2), B$3, C$3), B$4, C$4), B$5, C$5)
```

If you put the above into cell `D1` and drag/fill down,
the `A1` will update to `A2`, `A3`, etc.,
but the substitute string parameters (`B$1`, `C$1`, `B$2`, `C$2`, etc.)
will not change. 
I believe that it’s obvious that
this performs the `B1` → `C1` substitution on `A1`,
then performs the `B2` → `C2` substitution
on the result from the first substitution,
then performs the `B3` → `C3` substitution
on the result from the second substitution, and so on.

This is awkward for five substitutions,
and rapidly becomes unwieldy for more. 
If you may want to do many substitutions (say, up to 312),
use helper columns:

- Set `AA1` to

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(A1, INDEX($B:$B, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)), INDEX($C:$C, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)))
  ```

  This is equivalent to `=SUBSTITUTE(A1, B1, C1)`,
  but it gets the `B1` and `C1` values dynamically
  by taking the column number (`AA` → 27)
  and subtracting 26 (the column number of column `Z`),
  and using the result (1) as the row number in the `B` and `C` columns.
- Drag/fill `AA1` to `AB1`, so it becomes

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(B1, INDEX($B:$B, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)), INDEX($C:$C, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)))
  ```

  and change `B1` to `AA1`, so it becomes

  ```
  =SUBSTITUTE(AA1, INDEX($B:$B, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)), INDEX($C:$C, COLUMN()-COLUMN($Z1)))
  ```

  This is equivalent to `=SUBSTITUTE(AA1, B2, C2)`,
  which is equivalent to `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, B1, C1), B2, C2)`.
- Drag/fill `AB1` to `LZ1`. 
  This will be the result of `A1`
  with all the substitutions from `B1:C1` to `B312:C312` applied
  (because `L` is the 12th letter, and 12×26 is 312).
- Set `D1` to `=LZ1`, to reflect the result of all the substitutions.
- Drag/fill `D1` and `AA1:LZ1` down as far as you have data in column `A`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd hoped for a clever way to do this using a single array formula, but couldn't find one (I'd love to be proved wrong!)  I think the only way to do it with a single formula per line of input is to nest `SUBSTITUTE` functions, as per [@G-Man's answer](https://superuser.com/q/1288822/354511#1289213).  Sadly, this strategy won't work for 300 substitutions, as Excel has a [limitation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) that functions can only nest 64 levels deep (or 7 before Excel 2007).

Hence I think you'll need helper columns (which you can always hide if it helps with presentation).  The method below uses simpler formulas than G-Man's.  It uses a few more helper cells than his: one column per input string × one row per substitution plus one:

- Starting with the worksheet laid out as per your example, insert a blank row at the top of the page.
  Select cells `F1:H1`, type the formula `=TRANSPOSE(A2:A4)` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, so it gets entered as an array formula.  You should see curly braces appear around the formula, and the cells should fill with your input strings.
- In cell `F2`, enter the formula `=SUBSTITUTE(F1,$B2,$C2)`.  Copy this formula across and down to fill all of `F2:H6`.  Your desired output will appear in `F6:H6`.
- To get your output back to column `D`, select `D2:D4` and enter the formula `=TRANSPOSE(F6:H6)`.
  As before, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so it works as an array formula.

This should scale easily for more input strings (use more columns) or substitutions (use more rows); just adjust the ranges accordingly.  If you don't actually need the input and output in columns, you can easily do without the `TRANSPOSE` formulae too; just enter your input in the top row to start with.

Comment: Nice  improvement.

Answer (score 2):

While I know you were after a formula-based solution, I thought a VBA version would be helpful for reference, as I couldn't find one online:

```
Function MULTISUB(aString As String, oldVals As Range, newVals As Range) As Variant
    oldW = oldVals.Columns.Count
    oldH = oldVals.Rows.Count

    If (oldW = newVals.Columns.Count) And (oldH = newVals.Rows.Count) And (oldW = 1 Or oldH = 1) Then
        MULTISUB = aString
        For i = 1 To oldVals.Count
            MULTISUB = Replace(MULTISUB, oldVals.Cells(i), newVals.Cells(i))
        Next i
    Else
        MULTISUB = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    End If
End Function
```

For your example, you would enter `=MULTISUB(A1,$B$1:$B$5,$C$1:$C$5)` in cell `D1` and copy it down to `D3`.

The function takes a string and two ranges.  It searches the string for the values in each cell in the first range, and replaces them with the values of the corresponding cells in the second range.  If the two ranges aren't the same shape and size, it returns `#REF`.

Comment: Thanks for contributing this.  If I had written this, I would impose a restriction that one of the dimensions of the `xxxVals` ranges must be 1, partly because it becomes much harder for a human being to interpret / understand the rules if they aren’t laid out side-by-side (in one dimension or the other).  Alternatively (at the very least), you should document ***extremely** prominently* that your function processes rows first and then columns (i.e., normal page text-reading order for Western languages like English).  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This is because a user who uses regions of two columns and 150 rows might expect the opposite (i.e., normal ***column / list*** reading order: first column top to bottom, and then second column top to bottom), and order matters.  Note in the OP’s example that the `B5` → `C5` (“Nice. Thanks” → “Fine, THANKS”) substitution rule won’t affect the `A3` input (``"Nice! thanks"``) unless the `B1` → `C1` (“!” → “&”) and `B2` → `C2` (“&” → “.”) rules are applied first (in that order).

Comment: Good point. I've edited my answer to check that the ranges are 1-dimensional, which also means only one loop is needed to iterate through all the cells.

Comment: Hi JRI thanks for your comment, looks interesting, though my excel in portuguese seems not to have the MULTISUB function. I tried it directly in excel while i dont have the vba...

Comment: `MULTISUB` is a User-Defined Function, not part of the standard library of Excel functions. To make it work you would need to enable the Developer menu in Excel, and enter the code from the answer in a new module in the Visual Basic editor. If you want to try, Google for "Excel UDF tutorial".

Comment: See also [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/354511)