# How can I count unique selections from multiple selections in a drop down list (Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I would like to count the number of unique selections from a column that contains multiple selections from a drop down list.

For example, column B3 contains,

> Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday

The count function returns a value of 1 instead of 3 - is there any way to count the three days distinctly? Thank you!

*Multiple selections from a drop down list was made possible using the VBA code from: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JU7G_Tna2zPBtcG2TlarxKCTbuinNsg5LwBqzmuJYK8/edit*

Comment: Do yo uneed a VBA solution or would a formula do?

Comment: Both will be good for my learning experience but a formula would be great! Thank you so much! @cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a UDF. (I'm not even sure it's possible with a standard formula.)

With a worksheet set up like this:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Copy-paste the following code to a standard module:

```
'============================================================================================
' Module     : <any standard module>
' Version    : 0.1.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : (Optional) Microsoft Scripting Runtime   [Scripting]
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1332369/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Public Function CountDistintMultiSelections _
                ( _
                           count_array As Range _
                ) _
       As Long

  Dim dictSelections As Object                              '##Early Bound## As Scripting.Dictionary
  Set dictSelections = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '##Early Bound## = New Dictionary

  Dim celCell As Range
  For Each celCell In Intersect(count_array, count_array.Parent.UsedRange)
    Dim varSelections As Variant
    varSelections = Split(celCell.Value2, ", ")
    Dim varSelection As Variant
    For Each varSelection In varSelections
      If dictSelections.Exists(varSelection) Then
        dictSelections(varSelection) = dictSelections(varSelection) + 1
      Else
        dictSelections.Add varSelection, 1
      End If
    Next varSelection
  Next celCell
  CountDistintMultiSelections = dictSelections.Count

End Function
```

Enter the following formula in `C2`:

```dart
=CountDistintMultiSelections(B:B)
```

---

**Explanation:**

The code uses the `Split()` function to separate out the individual selections in each cell, and a dictionary to count the unique selections.

**Notes:**

To install the UDF, follow these steps:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Select the menu item `Insert` → `Module`
- Paste the code in the main window

Comment: Hi, how would I be able to compute this in the spreadsheet? Do I use the COUNT function or? Thank you!

Comment: @pundadesh Oops, sorry! I left out the explicit instructions. I've updated the answer to show how to call the UDF from a cell. Plus I've updated the UDF with a slightly better version. I've also added instruction for installing the UDF. You may need to enable macros, and you have to save as a macro-enabled workbook.

Comment: See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988)  for general information on using VBA.

Comment: @Scott Thanks for the link. I *did* do a quick search for a tutorial a while back. Don't know how I missed finding that post.