# Excel: take data from other files, sort them alphabetically and return the totals

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have Excel files to record the sales of the company I work for, one file for each month (e.g., "Sales of January 2019.xlsx"). Each of these files has sheets for each day, and each sheet in turn has two tables, one for the morning shift and another for the evening shift. The sales in these tables are recorded chronologically as they happen:

[image]

Now I have another file, which would be named "Totalizer.xlsx", with two sheets, one called "Data", and another called "Totals". In "Data" I have two variables, "File", wherein I'll put the name of the file I want to extract the data from, and another called "Sheet" to indicate the specific sheet to work with:

[image]

After receiving this input, Excel should automatically take the information from the two shifts of the specified day, sort them alphabetically and display the totals in the "Totals" sheet this way:

[image]

Is this possible to do? And if so, how could I do it?

PS: If you wonder why I don't include this totalizer in the files of the sales, that's because they're password-protected and can't be modified.

Comment: could you provide some sample files?

Comment: (1) So you want to read, sort and total the sales for one day at a time?  It’s not a problem, but I don’t understand how this is useful. (2) I don’t see anything here that would be really hard to do.  I’m a big fan of worksheet functions, but VBA is probably better suited to this. (3) We have a saying around here: “Super User is not a script-writing service.”  You’re more likely to get help here if you try something, and come back and ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @GauravJoseph: I'll try to make some when I'm home. I can't upload the real files for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Scott "I don’t understand how this is useful." - That's something I need to do at the end of each day. The tickets of each day are organized alphabetically and totalized, but the file has nothing to calculate it so I need to do manually. "try something, and come back and ask a specific question if you get stuck." - I don't know where to start. I'm not someone who asks questions when I can do it by myself, but I'm blank here. I know how to work with formulas, but no formula that I know can do this. I don't need the script written for me but at least to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: OK; I told you that I thought VBA was the best approach.  [This site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Library-Reference/Concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office "Getting started with VBA in Office") and [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/language-reference "Language reference for Visual Basic for Applications (VBA)") (at microsoft.com) are useful references, but it’s like trying to learn how to drive by reading a roadmap.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  [This](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988 "How do I add VBA in MS Office?") is the official Super User starter’s guide for using VBA with Microsoft Office, and [this search](https://superuser.com/search?q=excel*+vba "Super User posts containing ‘excel*’ and ‘vba’") will lead you to nearly four thousand Super User posts about Excel and VBA.  Hundreds of them have good examples of working code (you might want to sort by votes).

Comment: @Scott Alright, thank you, I'll look into it. I've never used VBA but I know other programming languages, so I don't think this'll be difficult. At least knowing that this is achievable through VBA points me in the direction I wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder of PowerPivot might be a good tool for you to look into. It will allow you to create pivot tables/reports based off data from multiple sources.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'd rather not have to depend of add-ins since this has to be compatible with multiple computers. Most of them use Office 2010 in which PowerPivot is not included by default.