# Dynamic worksheet name in formular

Tags: worksheet-function, cross-reference

I have an Excel workbook with 101 worksheets. The 1st worksheet shall provide me with a reference of cell A1 of all following 100 worksheets. Which formula can be used without manually linking each worksheet?

I have not current solution.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post to show how you've tried to solve this problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Indirect()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function.

If the cell `B6` has a sheet name, then the formula `=INDIRECT("'"&B6&"'!A1")` will return the value from `A1` in that sheet. (It won't copy any formatting, just the value.)

If you need a list of all the sheets names in your large workbook, VBA can handle that. [Add this function to a module](https://superuser.com/q/801609/348859) and run it to dump all the sheet names in column `A` of the active sheet. NOTE: This will overwrite anything you already have in those cells so make sure the active sheet is a blank one.

```
Sub dumpSheetNamesToActiveSheet()
    For r = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(r).Name
    Next
End Sub
```