# Word-document comments switch to "Author" when saving the file

Tags: microsoft-word, comments

When I create a Word document on my computer, make some comments, save it and reopen it, all the comment names change to "Author" and the checkbox under `TrustCenter Settings > Remove properties and personal information when the file is saved` is automatically checked. This happens when I save the file on a network location and it doesnt happen on my local computer.

What could be the issue here and what can I do to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the path of network location as one Trusted Location in TrustedCenter Settings?

Please also go to
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`,
back it up first, then right click `Normal.dotm`, open it,
press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, and add the macro below:

```vb
Public Sub AutoOpen()

    ActiveDocument.RemovePersonalInformation = False

End Sub
```

See [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988) for general information.

Comment: @Scott Thanks again~~~  I would pay more attention to the format of my reply later.