# Auto delete a value after a certain date is passed

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm making a work registration list for myself and my colleagues. 
In this workbook I created, we have a certain amount of free days we can use, but we need to use those free days before a certain date. 
If we don't use them, they will pass away. 
So I need to create a code that will automatically delete those free days
if they don't get used up before the deadline.
but this also needs to happen on opening the file and on multiple sheets
So, for example:

I have an cell A1 where 240:00 hours stands in, I want to use a second cell A2 with an date that is one year and 180 days later, and if there is still a value left in cell A1 that it will changed to 0:00.

I need it to work on different cells and also with different times, because some free days will pass after one year and 180 days, and some free days after 5 years.

I know to put code in VBA and create macro's, but i don't know how to write code for VBA, only ajust it a little bit

Comment: Please [edit] the post & add a new Tag VBA  or VBA Macro as well be specific that you are comfortable with VBA and could implement it properly,,, otherwise the solution posted below should be considered irrelevant and possibly down voted !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you realize that cells (and the formulas and functions they contain)
cannot *modify* other cells. 
Cells can *display* misleading values;
e.g., you could *have* a non-zero value stored in the worksheet,
but display it as “0” or blank. 
VBA *can* modify cells.

From your description of the situation,
I assume that you want to actually delete the “free days” values,
and so you want VBA.

You say you want this to work on multiple cells at once,
but you don’t say how they are designated. 
I assumed that it was OK to hard-code a list of cells in the VBA source. 
If you need some other approach, please edit your question to specify it.

Create the following VBA routine. 
Use [How do I add VBA in MS Office?](https://superuser.com/q/801609/150988) for reference if you need to. 
Change the `cell_list` value
to list the cells that contain “free days” values.

```vb
Sub auto_delete()
    Dim cell_list, this_cell As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim today_date As Date

    today_date = Date
    cell_list = "A1,B1"
    For i = 0 To UBound(Split(cell_list, ","))
        this_cell = Split(cell_list, ",")(i)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Range(this_cell) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox this_cell + " is not a valid cell designation."
            Exit For
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Range(this_cell).Count <> 1 Then
            MsgBox this_cell + " appears to be a range.  Please specify individual cells only."
            Exit For
        End If
        If Range(this_cell).Cells(2, 1).Value < today_date Then
            ' in the past
            Range(this_cell).Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Notes:

- Setting `cell_list` to a comma-separated string
  is a somewhat klugy way of specifying a list of values. 
  But apparently my version of VBA is old and out-of-date;
  I tried cleaner (more modern?) techniques, and they didn’t work.
- `Split(cell_list, ",")` does what it looks like —
  it splits the `cell_list` into component words, using comma as a separator,
  and creates an array of values.
- `UBound(Split(cell_list, ","))` gives the highest (upper bound) index
  into the array. 
  (This is one less than the number of values, because the indices start at 0.)
- `For i = 0 To (the_above)`
  loops through the values in the array.
- `Split(cell_list, ",")(i)`
  indexes into the array and returns the *`i`*th value.
- I needed to use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0`
  to test for invalid cell references; I’m not sure why.
- `Range(this_cell).Cells(2, 1).Value`
  refers to the cell below the current one. 
  For example, if `this_cell` is `A1`,
  then this refers to `A2`, where the expiration date is.

I believe that the rest is self-explanatory.

Before:

[image: Spreadsheet: A1 has 16, A2 has 1-Jul-2021, B1 has 42, B2 has 1-Nov-2021]

After:

[image: same as above except A1 is blank]

Invoke the above routine manually or automatically;
whichever is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: thank you very much, this code from you works good. but now i came to one new challange.  I have put your code in the thisworkbook in VBA with Private Sub Workbook()when for opening the code, but now when i open the excel sheet the code only runs on the selected sheet when it got closed, but not on the other sheets in the workbook. to let my workbook work it needs to run the code on all the sheets.